# Show Multiple rows in horizontal in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a requirement that I need to show my records in a gridview like this:

image           image
name            name
address         address

image           image
name            name
address         address

and so on........

I am unable to show my records like in the above format. Could it be possible in a grid view or I need to use any other control. please guide me.

Comment: It is better to use repeater in this scenario.In repeater you made your custom designing easily.

Comment: will you please give me a hint of code or sample example here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Datalist` which will allow you to set `RepeatDirection` to display vertically or horizontally. and `RepeatColumns` for the number of columns to display.

and for the column headers you can do this:

```
Rows[0].HeaderCell.value = "image";
```

........
and so on for others.

check this for more info:
[Datalist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with a jquery plugin--

[gridview using jquery](http://jquerygridview.com/)

OR check this link also for grid view --

[Gridview jquery tips and tricks](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article970-aspnet-gridview-jquery-tips-and-tricks-part-1.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I need to show two Rows(from database) and show these two in a single Row of the Gridview.. did you understand now?